# iCloud calendar integration through web api

Tags: ios, oauth, calendar, caldav, icloud-api

I was looking for available options of integrating my web application events with iCloud calendar.

I was thinking about web API provided by Apple to do the job, but my search ended with 2 options only:

1- CALDAV, which requires storage of client applie id and password in my database
2- iOS app, which is not feasible for me in the tome being.

Is there a method of integration with the iCloud calendar using more secure and safe method like oAuth (even through caldav protocol)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that iCloud already supports oAuth (if it does, it's not documented ;-).

How exactly do you want to integrate with iCloud? If you just need to consume events from an iCloud calendar, subscribed calendars might be an option. If you share an iCloud calendar with the 'public', it'll essentially give you a URL with a token.